# Unchecking "Show skipped reviews" on the last page leads to an empty review list

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits

When user's [review queue history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/history) have a different number of pages for with and without skipped items, navigation to the last page and unchecking the box "Show skipped reviews" leads to a page which says

> You have not reviewed any suggested edits yet.

> [image]

You can achieve the same behavior by manually specify non existing page number in the URL, e.g. `page=123456`