# "Show skipped reviews" is forcibly checked every time I navigate to another page

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, navigation, review-history

*This is most likely only reproducible by users with 10k+ rep.*

If you go to the Review History of any review queue, click on "My reviews", scroll down to the pagination component, and click on any page number in order to navigate to that page, you'll notice that the "Show skipped reviews" checkbox becomes checked all of a sudden and the list now displays skipped reviews. So, you uncheck it and navigate to another page, and it gets automatically checked again.

Here's a demo:

[image]

This happens because the href of the page number elements only explicitly sets the `skipped` param value when the checkbox is checked:

```
/history?page=n&userid=XXXX&skipped=true
```

However, when the checkbox is unchecked, the href becomes:

```
/history?page=n&userid=XXXX
```

And apparently, it defaults to true in the backend.

Note that clicking the "My reviews" tab header, on the other hand, always explicitly sets the `skipped` param value depending on the state of the checkbox, defaulting to *false* when coming from the "All reviews" tab.

Can this please be fixed?

Comment: Somewhat related: [Unchecking "Show skipped reviews" on the last page leads to an empty review list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/362383/348196)